# Error trying to run first python script on IIS

Tags: iis, python-3.x

I followed the steps in a respose to how to Set up Python for IIS :
[Python on IIS: how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823316/python-on-iis-how?s=554506ed-4da3-4f4b-a548-0944c9bad077)

But when I write my script and try running it it fails on the first line. I get this error message:

> HTTP Error 502.2 - Bad Gateway The specified CGI application
>   misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The
>   headers it did return are " File
>   "C:\Development\Python\helloworld.py", line 1 print 'Content-Type:
>   text/plain' ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax ".

This is my frist attempt at python. What is going wrong?

Comment: Which python version did you use? If you're on python 3, you need parentheses: e.g., `print('Content-Type: text/plain')`

Comment: yes it is 3. So is it every print statement needs brackets? what's the syntax changes with 3?

Comment: See my comment below. If it satisfies your question, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your example `helloworld.py` needs to be changed to:

```
print('Content-Type: text/plain')
print('')
print('Hello, world!')
```

Python 3 changed print to use function call syntax (which can be used in python 2).

Comment: It works for me just using: print() at the top of my code, I did not need to use print('Content-Type: text/plain')