# 502 error on python page

Tags: python, iis-7

I just installed python 27 and I'm trying to run a python page through my localhost server. I'm getting this error:

HTTP Error 502.2 - Bad Gateway
The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The headers it did return are "".

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="pass", # your password
                      db="my_dbs") # name of the data base

cur = db.cursor() 

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM myTable")

# print all the first cell of all the rows
for row in cur.fetchall() :
    print(row[0])
```

I'm using Windows 7.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is it an IIS configuration problem? I have a python handler mapping:

```
pythonHandler
Path: *.py
State: Enabled
Path Type: Unspecified
Handler: CGIModule
Entry Type: Local
```

Answer (score 0):

IIS is looking for a HTTP response, but you're responding with a listing of raw data.

The following code outputs a plain text web page. It prints the number of rows found, and the contents of the first column of each row of data.

```
import MySQLdb

print 'Content-type: text/plain'
print

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="pass", # your password
                      db="my_dbs") # name of the data base

cur = db.cursor() 

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM myTable")

rows = cur.fetchall()
print "found {} rows".format(len(rows))

# print all the first cell of all the rows
for row in rows:
    print(row[0])
```

This minimal header marks the data as a HTTP response, as plain text, so the browser will correctly show you the data.

Comment: I added that line. Now I'm no longer getting an error, but I'm also not getting any listing of data, so I'm not sure right now what the problem is.

Comment: @LauraNMS thanks for the feedback! I've updated the code to give more information

Comment: thank you, shavenwarthog. it turned out iss wasn't configured right for python. i got the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823316/python-on-iis-how?s=554506ed-4da3-4f4b-a548-0944c9bad077

Comment: unfortunately, I got the answer from stackoverflow.com/questions/6823316/, but thank you very much for your response!