# Python IIS is not working in FireFox, but works in IE and Chrome

Tags: python, iis

I am attempting to set up Python on my IIS. I have followed the steps in the stack overflow article:

[Python on IIS: how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823316/python-on-iis-how)

I had originally gotten this to work and was getting scripts to display outputs. However, I attempted to install another version of Python. After following the same steps, I am now always getting prompted to download the script rather than it running it.

When I go to the directory localhost/py/python_test.py, I get the prompt below.

It should be displaying a simple print() message. What am I missing? I have set up the appropriate mappings as in that stack overflow article and I had previously gotten it to work. I don't know why it is prompting me to download the script this time.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure things are set up correctly per Step 7 of the linked s.o. article.

Comment: @martineau This only seems to be happening on FireFox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the steps in Mozilla's article

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/941019

and restarted browser. I was able to view my python files in Firefox afterwards.