# How to use python 3.x scripts on IIS windows 10

Tags: python, iis, iis-10

Im trying to run python 3.x scripts on IIS and I came across this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9745836/5457561

I tried this method and it didn't seem to work and I recieved `The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The headers it did return are " File "C:\dev\python\HelloWorld.py", line 1 print 'Content-Type: text/plain' ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'` ".

I was just wondering whether there was a method to get past this and use python 3.x scripts on IIS 10

Comment: Correction: That is a Python *2* script.  If it were Python 3, there would be parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fix the syntax error in "C:\dev\python\HelloWorld.py".