# import seaborn error: underlying buffer has been detached

Tags: python, iis, flask, import, seaborn

My python-flask web application which uses "import seaborn" is working fine in my local machine. But when I am trying to deploy the web application on server (IIS from microsoft), the application crashes.
Since its not possible to console log error in server, so I enclosed my "import seaborn" statement in try-except clause and logged the traceback error in a file.

This is what I am getting:[image]

Any idea why this is happening. Deployment of the application to the server is stopped because of this error.

Comment: It's a bit shocking - to run flask app on IIS. Are you obliged to use Windows and IIS to run your flask app?

Comment: Yup no other choice. Organizational constraints. :( any idea?

Comment: There were similar questions on SO. This is one of them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823316/python-on-iis-how. Just make sure you install all packages including `seaborn`. I also recommend using virtualenv if you don't use it.

Comment: See we have already deployed a number of python flask applications on iis and they are working fine. As for seaborn insatallation, all packages are installed properly. Any idea what that error:"underlying buffer has been detached" mean?

Comment: Also, "import seaborn" is working fine in cmd of the iis server but when we are trying to deploy it we are getting this error.

Comment: @Nurjan Was there any resolution to this? I'm having a weird interaction with seaborn and IIS. Same error and I can't figure out what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like wfastcgi and ipython don't like eachother.

Uninstalling ipython solved the problem for me (although I can't use my jupyter notebooks anymore).