# How to install and run python script on Microsoft server

Tags: python, server

Guys and ladies. I am new to programming. I have written some script.It just checks whether some data is correct or not.  I want that script to run 24*7 on Microsoft server at job (not on my PC). Please let me know how to do that.

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python on IIS: how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823316/python-on-iis-how)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from general server set-up, you will just need to download Python like you would on any server.

As for the running, something like `python yourScript.py` would work fine. In order to run it 24/7, you need to put your entire script in a `while(True):` loop so that it never stops running. Note that you should also include some **DECENT** error handling in the event on an issue so that it doesn't just crash.

Comment: how to download on python on server?