# How can I eliminate 401 error on IIS when calling Python script?

Tags: python, iis

I am testing Python 3.6 on Windows iis 10.0 and get the error 401 from browser when I call a .py file.

- I have iis working on ASP pages and HTML
- I have phyton.exe installed and working
- I have added a .py handler in iis
- I have tried to allow anonymous access and set up authorization as IUSR in iis
- ( And I allowed IUSR and IIS_IUSR... Full access on application directory)

I looked on Google and tried out many suggetsions!
BUT No way to esecute the script!

Comment: 401 is authentication related error, but only the 404 error cannot reproduce your problem, please post detailed error information. and in iis authentication, which authentication methods you have enabled?

Comment: the error is 401 - Unauthorized: "Access is denied due to invalid credentials.Anonimous Authentication method. I tried also Pool Auth Identity, but same result.

Comment: You can try to use Windows Authentication. In the Authentication list, enable Windows Authentication option, and disable all other authentication options. and the account whose credentials are specified to access the portal has Read permisison to the Password Manager instalaltion directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `%s %s` at the end of the Python Interpreter address.

Comment: Hi @Fulcrum! Try to give some more information on how this resolves the issue.

Comment: @BenjaminLöffel Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823316/python-on-iis-how