# CS6 & Python scripting

Tags: python, html, css

I have written a couple of scripts and now I would like to make a web based front end to run those scripts so that its more user friendly where users can upload files and then click a few buttons to choose what they want in order to generate the configurations. As of now it works by the script using a path to the file. My question is , can i design the HTML using CS6 and then link python scripts to it, Or I have to learn and code in HTML using flask and Jinja2 templating for this to work. I am obviously not a website designer or have any experience in css,java or html

Comment: you can not link any script language on the server side.browser only communicate to server using `http`.but some template help do this easily,or you can choose ajax.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823316/python-on-iis-how